# unbind click to div

Tags: javascript, html, bind, jquery

unbind click to div. I have two divs .i want to unbind the click event to the inside div

when the page is loaded, i want to unbind the click events to `triangle`.
my JQuery code:

```
 $(".wrapper").unbind();
 $(".triangles").unbind();

 $(".triangles" ).click(function(){   //it is still clickable

  alert("hello u clicked me");
 });

<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="triangles">
     </div>
     <div class="triangles">
     </div>
     <div class="triangles">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.off()` to unbind the event, when you need to.

Example:

```
$(".triangles").off("click");
```

Another example: Here It will be clickable at first and not from the second time

```
$(".triangles" ).click(function(){
    alert("hello u clicked me");
    $(this).off('click'); //after this, $(".triangles") will not longer be clickable
});
```

Try it :)

---

Let me explain, what you did wrong in your codes

```
 $(".wrapper").unbind(); //unbinded all the events
 $(".triangles").unbind();  //unbinded all the events

 $(".triangles" ).click(function(){  //binded another click event
     alert("hello u clicked me"); //So of course it will be clickable
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're calling the unbind function after the click event is registered, not before. If the click event is registered after the unbind, then the click event will not be removed.

```
$(".triangles" ).click(function(){   //it is still clickable

    alert("hello u clicked me");
});

// this will remove the click event and all other handlers 
$(".wrapper").unbind();
$(".triangles").unbind();
```

Also, I'd like to point out a syntax error in your code. Your click event handler is missing the `);` that is needed to close it.

If you're going to remove and reapply the click event often, you may want to wrap it in another function:

```
function bindClick() {
    $(".triangles" ).click(function(){   //it is still clickable

        alert("hello u clicked me");
    });
}
```

Now you can just call `bindClick()` when you need to re-apply the click event.

Comment: thanks alot :) but one question. if I want to bind the event again. I have to bind it again right?

Comment: Yes. In order for the click event to work, it must be bound. unbinding removes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.triangles').on("click", function() {
    alert('something');
});

$('.triangles').off("click");
```